# Unable to validate model - ecoSpace is null

Tags: mdriven

I have a problem when trying to validate the model

Model Validation| Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ecoSpace
| System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
| Parameter name: ecoSpace

Further info: The GAC has 13992 VS2022 has 13993
Check for Update is now saying that 7.0.0.14002 is available but I get  "Do not get old!" There is a new version 14002 - Download and install? You currently run 13993" and when I press yes i get "Download failed! Unable  to download  exe, connected?"

And also at first https://www.mdriven.net/PublicDownloads/MDrivenFramework_7.0.0.14002_Nightly_vs2022.vsix And the response is - The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable but later this link now works but I still cannot update from within VS2022.

**I have installed 14002 but the GAC still says 13992**

Remote access to a virtual machine that has the problem is available .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be a VS2022 thing? Maybe there is a version mismatch between GAC and VS for MDriven assemblies.

If it is not version mismatch please send a copy of the project with instructions to support at mdriven.net so that we may repeat and understand.

The fallback for DB-evolve is the play-button, SQL persistence, Evolve from there.